# Map Box Navigation: Value of type 'Route' has no member 'coordinates'

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Value of type 'Route' has no member 'coordinates'

Getting this error while following a simple youtube tutorial. Trying to draw a route. Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Is it a problem with the pods?

These are the ones installed. Thank you!

```
    pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.6'
      pod 'MapboxCoreNavigation', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios.git', :tag => 'v1.0.0-alpha.1'
      pod 'MapboxNavigation', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios.git', :tag => 'v1.0.0-alpha.1'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you have created.

Comment: I would suggest you add some code snipped to make it easy for us to help you

Comment: @user3811212 does the following answer solves your issue?

Comment: Hey @user3811212 Just wanted to check did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Hello User did the following answer worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

So i managed to find the sample application and also the error.

Following is the code from the sample application
Which gives error as

> Value of type 'Route' has no member 'coordinates' @routes?.first?.coordinates

```
Directions.shared.calculate(routeOptions) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
        guard let routeCoordinates = routes?.first?.coordinates, error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        //
        // ❗️IMPORTANT❗️
        // Use `Directions.calculateRoutes(matching:completionHandler:)` for navigating on a map matching response.
        //
        let matchOptions = NavigationMatchOptions(coordinates: routeCoordinates)

        // By default, each waypoint separates two legs, so the user stops at each waypoint.
        // We want the user to navigate from the first coordinate to the last coordinate without any stops in between.
        // You can specify more intermediate waypoints here if you’d like.
        for waypoint in matchOptions.waypoints.dropFirst().dropLast() {
            waypoint.separatesLegs = false
        }

        Directions.shared.calculateRoutes(matching: matchOptions) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
            guard let route = routes?.first, error == nil else { return }

            // Set the route
            self.navigationViewController?.route = route
        }
    }
```

which has to get rewrite as below.

```
        Directions.shared.calculate(routeOptions) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
        guard let firstRoute = routes?.first, let waypoints = waypoints, error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        //
        // ❗️IMPORTANT❗️
        // Use `Directions.calculateRoutes(matching:completionHandler:)` for navigating on a map matching response.
        //

        let matchOptions = NavigationMatchOptions(waypoints: waypoints)

        // By default, each waypoint separates two legs, so the user stops at each waypoint.
        // We want the user to navigate from the first coordinate to the last coordinate without any stops in between.
        // You can specify more intermediate waypoints here if you’d like.
        for waypoint in matchOptions.waypoints.dropFirst().dropLast() {
            waypoint.separatesLegs = false
        }

        Directions.shared.calculateRoutes(matching: matchOptions) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
            guard let route = routes?.first, error == nil else { return }

            // Set the route
            self.navigationViewController?.route = route
        }
    }
```

Please check if this solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

Install below pod

```
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.2'  
pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.38.0'
```

And then write below code, it's working for me

```
if(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()){

self.CurrentLat = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude

self.CurrentLong = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude

let origin = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 
self.CurrentLat, longitude: self.CurrentLong), name: "Start Location")

let destination = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: yourDestinationLat, 
longitude:  yourDestinationLong), name: yourDestinationName)
// Set options
let options = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination])

// Request a route using MapboxDirections.swift
Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in

guard let route = routes?.first else {
SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Unable to create a route. Please try 
again.")
   return
}

let viewController = NavigationViewController(for: route)
viewController.delegate = self
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
}
```